# How do I make a translucent white-ish tape material in Cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, transparency

I am looking to make a translucent whiteish tape material like the image below. Can't seem to wrap my head around making it.

[image]

Comment: what did you try so far and what seems to be the problem? Technically you could be able to do this with higher roughness on a transparent object, if you need it more real then you would have to make it more complex but finding "how to make semi transparent/translucent tape" is surely covered by some tutorial

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like this is a good and easy starting point for you...
[image]

You can change how much is it transparent just by changing **Fac** value in mix shader
[image]

Now you can add anything more that you want to make it more realistic