Earplugs Silicone Material - how would you make it?
how would you guys go about setting up a photorealistic material for a silicone material of earplugs like you can see in the picture?
I havent figured it out, so I would be greatful for some advice.
Thank you!
Template picture

my version

material screenshot

EDIT: This question hasnt been answerd in other threads, for example in the fish tail thread the material looks very much like a harder more stiff material which this is not. Its supposed to look soft.

Did you try transparency with roughness ? Maybe with a translucent shader too ? What have you done so far ?

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/252509/how-do-i-make-a-translucent-white-ish-tape-material-in-cycles https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/258311/how-can-i-make-a-translucent-material-that-looks-like-this-axolotl-tail https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/80463/translucent-plastic-foam

Ive tried all shaders like:

translucent bsdf
glass bsdf
transparent bsdf
subsurface scattering bsdf
glossy and diffuse bsdf

In different combinations. I cant get it right. This is the problem basically in words:

subsurface scattering doesnt add transparency although subsurface scattering give some approximate results
when adding Glass bsdf the material becomes transparent, however it adds annoying specular highlights which are not supposed to be there
transparent bsdf doenst do it either because it makes visible hidden surface edges that shouldnt be visible

